# Remove first occurence in array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to delete from an array the first occurence, not all elements like the searched element
The array is something like:

```
groupedObjects: [
    { value: 125, currency: "EUR" }, 
    { value: 100, currency: "USD" },
    { value: 100, currency: "USD" }, 
    { value: 320, currency: "RON" }
]
```

The code I am using to solve the problem is:

```
var newArr = $.grep(amount, function(item, idx) {
    return item.currency == currency || item.value == val; }, true);
amount = newArr;
```

The problem with this code is that using it, it will delete all occurences found, not only the first one
Can someone help me?

Comment: how about you simply return `newArr[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(amount, function(idx, item) {
    if (item.currency == currency || item.value == val) {
        amount.splice(idx, 1); // Remove current item
        return false; // End the loop
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LVu6c/5/)

Comment: From what I can be sure of, deleting from an array that is currently on a loop can be very dangerous, since element[1] becomes element [0] after deletion and so on. And, I have allready tried this code and does not work

Comment: That's a problem if you continue looping through the array. But since this exits the loop after it deletes the element, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I had the arguments to the function in the wrong order. I've tested it now, see the demo.

Comment: Thank you, now it works, I have put the code inside my app. I have also tried it but without the 'return false;' and obviously it didn' worked

Comment: right. If you want to remove all matching elements using splice in a loop, you need to do it from highest index to 0. Then the renumbering doesn't mess up the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this 

**`groupedObjects.splice(0,1)`**

Take a look there http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: Sorry, it is not what I want from the answer, it has to be dynamic, think about an array with up to 1000 elements..